# Firefox 16 won't start from the gnome shell in 12.10

Tags: gnome, upgrade, firefox

I've just upgraded to 12.10 and firefox doesn't work properly.

When I start it from the gnome shell nothing happens, however system monitor shows me two processes called 'firefox', the last one of which has memory field as `N/A`.

But when I just type in terminal `firefox` it starts and there is only one entity of firefox in the system monitor.

Comment: This also affects gnome fallback. What is odd is that I made two installs. First a temporary test install, and I didn't get this bug. Second, on the proper install, I did. Perhaps it is because I never ran firefox under Unity on the first install.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a clean firefox profile so I'm guessing webapps preview did something bad to my old profile that I copied over from 12.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out to be easy.

Just disable all unity add-ons in firefox:

- Unity Desktop Integration
- Unity Websites Integration

and it will work.

To do that be sure there is no firefoxes in the processes in the system monitor and launch firefox in the terminal with the command `firefox`.

Comment: Thanks --- it works. Should be reported as a bug in launchpad. Is there a bug opened about this?